# Set property for tests in Intellij

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

TL;DR; How to easily run tests on class in Intellij, so that they execute `validate` phase in maven and have all Spring properties set.

I have imported maven project into Intellij. The tests are run using surefire, i.e. `mvn surefire:test -Dtest=SomeTest`. Some of those tests need to be have allocated port. Spring property with port number is set on `validate` phase using:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>port-allocator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>allocate-ports</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <ports>
                    <port>
                        <name>my-first-port</name>
                    </port>
                </ports>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run test from Intellij via `Right click on file > 'Run SomeTest'` it fails for tests that require `my-first-port`. Apparently `validate` phase is not being run.

I want to be able to run tests on single class with as small amount of click as possible. I need either:

- some way to run `validate` phase when `Right click > 'Run SomeTest'` happens, or
- create in Intellij maven run configuration which can be run on single class using command like `mvn surefire:test -Dtest=$CLASS_NAME$`, but I have no idea if any properties like functionality exists (`$CLASS_NAME$` would be a class name of currently opened class)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found partial solution in external tools of IntelliJ. I can easily setup there `cmd /C mvn test-compile surefire:test -Dtest=$FileClass$`. Thanks to it I can run single test with 3 click on `Tools > External Tools > MyTool`.

The big downside is that I cannot debug tests run this way. Unfortunately run cofiguration doesn't have macro `$FileClass$`, so I still have to setup separate run configuration for each class whenever I debug it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, intellij won't run any maven stuff when you run your tests, and what you're asking for probably won't work (afaik).

However, there is probably another way to achieve this. The plugin generates a random port and assigns it to the given variable. It is used to run multiple tests simultaneously on the same box and not have port conflicts. When you're running the test manually you probably don't have the same constraint and you can run it on a known port. To do that you can use IntelliJ's test run configuration dialog to set the value of `my-first-port` to a known value (say 56789).

Comment: Problem is port was just an example, and I don't want to simulate all actions from pom validate phase in a intellij configuration.